# How to build a ethernet HUB?

Tags: ethernet, network-interface

I want to build a simple as possible ethernet HUB.
I'm new to electronics (just made few arduino robots/projects but no big stuff).

I don't know where to start, can someone please explain me how it "electronically" works and what whould the best way to build one ? Also, I'd like it to be as small as possible (but that doesn't really matter for the first experiment)

I really want a Hub, not a switch or a router : i wanna capture all the data going through it

Comment: This is not a particularly simple project.. I suggest you start by researching ethernet technology and terminology ("MAC" and "PHY" etc)

Comment: i though that a hub was doing nothing more than repeating to other ports what was appening on one (and doing this for each port, so everybody recieve all the data going on through the cables connectesd to the hub)

Comment: @IggY - Right, and what about collisions? What are you going to send up to port 3 if you receive 100 % occupied buses at ports 1 and 2?

Comment: @stevenvh if i'm here asking for help it's because I need it, so I don't understand why you answer this way...
Could you be more precise on what you call collisions ?

Comment: @IggY - What I mean is that you can't just repeat on one port what you receive on another. Collisions are when two or more messages appear simultaneously on a bus. My example is about capacity. If you have three 100 Mbps buses and are receiving data at 100 Mbps (full capacity) on port 1 and 2 you would need 200 Mbps to pass all that to port 3, which is beyond the port's capabilities. In that case the hub will have control data flow: hold packages from port 1 to allow port 2 to send packages too. It's quite complex and requires some experience.

Comment: This is why I suggested that you research it - a hub is not simply connecting the ports together with amplification. You also didn't specify what your target speed was - even 10 mbit requires care to ensure you don't distort signals. You might be able to build a hub by gluing PHY ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHY_%28chip%29 ) together with a microcontroller.

Comment: Why do you want a hub?  From the information you have given us so far, this makes no sense.  There are reasons hubs have gone the way of dinosaurs and today we use mostly switches.  Also, ethernet switch chips will be more available.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : because I want to be able to sniff what's going through it.

Comment: @stevenvh : Ok now it's more clear, thank you :) !
pjc50 : I think i'll go for your solution, according on what stevenvh told me it will be hard to build it from scratch

Comment: a true hub doesn't care about collisions, everything goes to every port, it doesn't have or care about a MAC address. it's much simpler than implied in the discussion, the packets etc behave and see packets they would if they were on same coax, the devices themselves need to handle the collisions.

Also if you just want to sniff packets with a hub and don't care about the speed that much just buy an old 10mbit hub.

Answer (score 3):

1. Purchase an Ethernet hub chip. (Actually, these are hard to find these days; switches are much more common.)
2. Build the circuit shown in the chip's Application Notes or Reference Design.

If you really care about the distinction between a hub and a switch, there's some useful information [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HubReference).

Comment: I really want a hub ;) (it's for sniffing purpose)

Would this : http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/ethernetcontrollers could be able to be used as a hub chip ? if not, how should I search for a hub chip ?
Can I easily stop the "learning" capacity of a switch chip to make it behave like a hub ?

Comment: No, that chip would not be a good basis for building a hub.

Comment: Quite a lot of managed switches have a "port mirror" capability designed specifically for sniffing. If you just want to sniff ethernet, you could also get a 2-port computer configured as an ethernet bridge.

Comment: http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=13&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=25 slightly closer to what you want. Am still unclear why you want to build your own rather than buy.

Comment: http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Circuits/Interface/pethhub.htm
This looks like a mroe simpler and easer way of build one !

Answer (score 2):

If what you're looking to do is so snoop the traffic between two devices, you don't want a hub. What you want is a "Passive Tap". Here's a writeup from someone who made one.

http://hackaday.com/2008/09/14/passive-networking-tap/